# How to remove special characters from SQLite DB while importing from a CSV file in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, csv

I have a CSV file named barcode, I have successfully imported that file into my SQLite DB but the problem is the data is saving as it is as what we have in CSV file. 
The data im getting: 8.90103E+12, The data i wanted: 8901030382253.

Example:
**ITEM     - EAN_CODE**
100047253 - 8.90103E+12
100047252  - 8.90103E+12

I have two columns, the data in `Ean_code` is not getting proper into my db.
I have used the trim function but the o/p remains the same.

My code:

```
if (exportDir.exists()) {
            FileReader file = null;
            try {
                file = new FileReader(exportDir);

                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(file);
                String line = "";
                int iteration = 0;
                ArrayList<MasterDataModel2> arrayList_stock2 = new ArrayList<>();

                while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (iteration == 0) {
                        iteration++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    //StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String[] str = line.split(",");

                    arrayList_stock2.add(new MasterDataModel2(str[0].replace("\"", ""), str[1].replace("\"", "")));
                    //arrayList_stock2.add(new MasterDataModel2(str[0],str[1]));

                    Log.d("insertTotal", "Msg:" + lastId);
                }
                Log.e("size",String.valueOf(arrayList_stock2.size()));
                db.addAllMasterData2(arrayList_stock2);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //CallingImportantMethod.showToast(this, "File is not available");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //CallingImportantMethod.showToast(this, "Something wents wrong");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is this EAN_CODE has any significance in value. Because E+12 means in scientific notation is equals to 10^12. So if the exact value is significant,it may be not a good idea to just drop the notation but to convert it in to normal format and then store it.

Comment: No sir ean_code is in general format for example: 8.90103E+12 is actually ->8901071354103.

Comment: Okay. so your values in csv are comma separated or new line separated. Because i don't understand why you split lines by comma. It'll  be better if you can post a small example on how data are in the csv itself.

Comment: Sir it is not comma seperated but when opening in notepad it shows comma seperated.

Comment: Can you kindly add a screen shot of the csv. If it is big, a small part of it will do

Comment: yes sir here it is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vD_YiI5K88l_adQ9-Ark5oQWIRNPqNjk/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This below code is incorrect.

```
arrayList_stock2.add(new MasterDataModel2(str[0].replace("\"", ""), str[1].replace("\"", "")));
```

`\` is special escape character, so you need `\\` to escape it. Even though unrelated to the original problem suggest you to read [this](https://way2java.com/java-introduction/backslash-in-java/) to have a clear idea about usage of backslashes in java.

So back to the problem, i guess you really don't need to call the `str[].replace()`. Correct me if i am wrong.

```
arrayList_stock2.add(new MasterDataModel2(str[0].trim(), str[1].trim()));
```

I think above code segment will be enough.

Edit: for your actual problem you can use below. To avoid null issues you may need to check that also.

```
if(str[1] != null) {
    Double eanCodeDouble = Double.parseDouble(str[1]);
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    String eanCodeString = nf.format(eanCodeDouble);
    System.out.println(resultedString);
} else {
    String eanCodeString = '';
}

if(str[0] == null) {
   str[0] = '';
}
    arrayList_stock2.add(new MasterDataModel2(str[0].trim(), eanCodeString));
```

Comment: Brother i have used this trim function as i have mentioned in my problem still getting the same output.

Comment: What do you mean by "proper". Clearly mention that how the data you want to be saved and how it is actually saving now?

Comment: The data im getting: 8.90103E+12, The data i wanted: 8901030382253.

Comment: Ah i see. So you want to store the EAN_CODE in number format even though they are being read from the csv in scientific format. I have updated the answer. I guess that can solve your problem. Just update me if anything is wrong.

Comment: Thanku for you efforts but m getting this now :  Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1 idk what to do..I have solved the error but still getting the same o/p brother...

Comment: brother thanku again! everything is working fine but when the cells are empty the app crashes by showing : empty string exception. How to solve this pls..

Comment: Yes. That is because of the split(). It can not be called for null values. Cells are empty means that the line is null. So calling split() method on nulls will throw an exception. To avoid this you have to check whether the line is null or not before the rest of the code is executed.

Comment: Bro this is my code: String[] str   = line.split(",");
                    String[] str2  = line.split(",");

                    Double eanCodeDouble = Double.parseDouble(str2[0]);
                    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
                    String eanCodeString = nf.format(eanCodeDouble);                     arrayList_stock2.add(new MasterDataModel2(String.valueOf(eanCodeString).replaceAll(",",""),String.valueOf(str[1]).replaceAll("\"","")));
can u help me again???

Comment: why do you split the 'line' twice. str and str2 will get the same  result?

Comment: yeah i know i just want to seperate them just to understand easily. str is for position '0' and str2 is for position '1'.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please refer it as an example. It may not exactly resolve your issue. But something along that will do.

Comment: u have already helped me a lot ..ill try that.. good day mate!! thanku..